# $select=discipline &$filter=source_system eq 'myExperts'&facets=source_system

Tags: filter, facet, acs

This is the error I am facing while running the query I am working on acs:

> "The request is invalid. Details: parameters : When trying to read a null collection parameter value in JSON Light, a node of type 'PrimitiveValue'  with the value

Is filter and facets can work simultaneously?